# jQuery find highest parent TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a code for a form contained within a table. I'm writing (with jQuery) a function to highlight the parent `<td>` of each `<input>` element. That part is simple - the code is just:

```
$('.myForm input').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    })
```

The more complicated part is that some text fields are inside of a second table nested within a `<td>` of the first table. It would look like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <--cell I want to add the class to
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text'></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

So my question is this: is there a way to use one jQuery statement to find the highest parent `<td>` of the `<input>` element? So in other words, can I combine:

```
$('.myForm input').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    })
```

and

```
$('.myForm input').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
    })
```

into one function?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The best solution is to add a class to the table you actually want to target. This means that you could update the markup in future without necessarily breaking the JS, by doing something like `$(this).closest('.targetElement').addClass('active')`.

If you *can't* do that, you can use `parents('td').last()`.  This selects all `td` parent elements and then gets the last one.

```
$('.myForm input').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('td').last().addClass('active');
})
```

See the jQuery manual:

- [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)
- [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents)
- [`last`](http://api.jquery.com/last)

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this:

```
$('.myForm input').click(function(){
   $(this).parents('td').last().addClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest trying:

```
 $(this).parents("td").last()
```

It will find all table cell ancestors of the current element. The last one should contain the highest level table cell element.

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
$(this).parents('td:last');
```

or

```
$(this).parents('td').last();
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your top-level td element a class name:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="topTD"> <--cell I want to add the class to
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text'></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>


$('.myForm input').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('td.topTD').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick&dirty :)

```
$(this).parents('td')[--$(this).parents('td').length]
```

Comment: Your code runs the selection twice (unnecessary overhead) and performs the same operation as [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/).